# Markov chain and conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, markov-process

If I define a Markov chain,
$$
A\to B\to C
\\P(A,B,C)=P(A)P(B|A)P(C|B)
$$
Can I derive an expression for $P(C|A)$?

I feel like this should be $P(C|B)P(B|A)$, but I am not seeing how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your direction is correct, but you need to sum that expression over all possible $b$:

$$P(C=c|A=a)=\sum_b P(B=b|A=a)P(C=c|B=b)$$

It should cover all the paths from $A=a$ to $C=c$.

Comment: Thanks! I was beginning to think along those lines during yesterday's service outage, but I couldn't quite crystallize it.  Your answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: Follow up (and apologies if my notation is terrible), but would this carry over to the continuous case like

$$P_{C|A}(\mathbf{c}|\mathbf{a})=\int _\mathsf{R}P_{C|B}(\mathbf{a}|\mathbf{b})P_{B|A}(\mathbf{b}|\mathbf{a})d\mathbf{b} $$

Comment: Sorry that should be c|b in the first term on the right.

Comment: Yes, that is correct